# Array concatenation replacing negative values with 0

Tags: matlab, octave

I'am a matlab newbie and having trouble with matrix concatenation. The first column of the 'Dones' matrix below has the values '0' and not '-1'. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
getones = ones(size(D,1),1);
negative = getones * -1;
Dones = cat(2,negative,D);
disp(Dones);
```

Comment: Those sequence of commands should work.  I don't see anything wrong with that syntax.  It should place the negative vector of 1s first before your D matrix.  Can you show me what your `D` matrix looks like?

Answer (score 0):

The code you are using seems correct to me, however it's quite inefficient. Let me introduce you the function `prepad`. What you are trying to can be replaced with:

```
prepad (D, columns (D) +1, -1, 2)
```

This function will prepad the matrix `D` so that its number of columns (columns is the second dimension, the last argument) is `columns (D) +1`, with the -1 value.